# binding and ko.toJSON not working as expected

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm learning KO and trying to create a simple list item add/remove. but I have the following questions.

Q1: If you click Add without enter a name, the item you just add will have `result` as name. why and how to prevent it while allowing empty as valid inputs?

Q2: I would like to use the `<pre>` tag to show the JSON of current view model, but it's not showing anything. But the button shows something. **I figured this one out. I need to use `ko.toJSON($data, null, 4)`**.

Q3: It's related to Q2, the button shows something, but what it shows seem to be weird. After you enter a few items, then click `debug` button. You'll see all the items in the view model are replaced by the last item you change.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TgD6a/).

CSS:

```
input[type=text], select {
    width:100px;
}
```

JS:

```
function foodie() {
    this.name;
    this.food;
}

function foodieApp() {
    var self = this;
    self.foodies = ko.observableArray();
    self.foodieToAdd = ko.observable(new foodie());

    self.addFoodie = function () {
        this.foodies.push(this.foodieToAdd());
    };

    self.delFoodie = function (foodieToDel) {
        self.foodies.remove(foodieToDel);
    };

    self.debug = function () {
        alert(ko.toJSON(self, null, 4));
    };
}

var app = new foodieApp();
ko.applyBindings(app);
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Foodie's Name
                <br/>
                <input type=text data-bind='value: foodieToAdd().name' />
            </td>
            <td>Foodie's Food
                <br/>
                <select data-bind='value: foodieToAdd().food'>
                    <option value=apple>Apple</option>
                    <option value=banana>Banana</option>
                    <option value=cherry>Cherry</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type=button value=Add data-bind='click: addFoodie' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind='foreach: foodies'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type=text data-bind='value: name' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select data-bind='value: food'>
                    <option value=apple data-bind>Apple</option>
                    <option value=banana>Banana</option>
                    <option value=cherry>Cherry</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type=button value=del data-bind='click: $parent.delFoodie' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type=button value=debug data-bind='click: debug' />
<!-- why the following <pre> tag is empty? -->
<pre data-bind='text: ko.toJSON(app, null, 4)'></pre>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/TgD6a/3/

--

- Q1: You were not initializing your `foodie` object
- Q2: `app` is not part of your ViewModel - it is the ViewModel.  Use `$root` to gain access to the top-level ViewModel
- Q3: This has to do with the way you are defining `foodieToAdd`.  Basically you are only ever creating one instance, so Knockout keeps adding the same object over and over.  Because you don't have observable properties knockout didn't update the UI.

In my fiddle I changed how `foodieToAdd` is defined.  It is now just a standard object, with two observable properties.  When you click `add` it clones `foodieToAdd` to create a new entry in the observableArray.

EDIT: See comments below for why knockout was picking up `result`.

--

```
function foodie(foodie) {
    this.name = ko.observable(foodie ? foodie.name() : '');
    this.food = ko.observable(foodie ? foodie.food() : '');
}

function foodieApp() {
    var self = this;
    self.foodies = ko.observableArray();
    self.foodieToAdd = new foodie();

    self.addFoodie = function () {
        this.foodies.push(new foodie(this.foodieToAdd));
    };

    self.delFoodie = function (foodieToDel) {
        self.foodies.remove(foodieToDel);
    };

    self.debug = function () {
        alert(ko.toJSON(self, null, 4));
    };
}

var app = new foodieApp();
ko.applyBindings(app);
```

Comment: This is all correct, but I can't figure out why `result` is getting placed in the `name` binding. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't exactly why, other than it has to with binding to properties are not initialized.  It looks like something in the DOM rendering logic of Knockout.  If you look at this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/TgD6a/4/) you'll see your debug rendering.  You'll see no name in your object, but you can change `result` to `res` and if you hit add it takes that value.

Comment: I did some debugging this morning, swapping in the debug version of knockout.  The reason `result` is getting picked up is actually quite simple, but it involves a little used JavaScript statement: `with`.

Knockout is evaluating this function:

`with($context){with($data||{}){return{'value': name, ... }}}`

The `with` statements add `$context` and `data` to the scope-chain where it will try to resolve `name`.  Neither of these have a `name` property, but `this` (which is Window) does... and it's `result`.  Try changing `name` to `foodieName` and we no longer have the unexpected `result`.